# Notificaciones push con Firebase, Android Studio, ESP32, Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, firebase, kotlin, push-notification, esp32

Cordial saludo.

Estoy realizando un proyecto con un ESP32 que al detectar gas natural gracias a un sensor MQ-4, emite un sonido de alarma y un led, aparte de eso quiero que cuando detecte el gas tambien envie una notificacion push, actualmente eh logrado enviar los datos del valor del gas a Firebase, pero quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de programar esta notificacion para que cuando le llegue un dato en especifico a la base de datos de Firebase este envie la notificacion.

Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Entre las apis que tienes acceso, además de firebase está el servicio de notificaciones que permite enviar un push directamente a cualquier dispositivo registrado en tu aplicación.